# How not to submit form, then submit it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have form with email input, one button which overlapse it, when I click on button, button is sliding across input so you can input email. When you click on button it must submit the form.

How do I make that?

```
<form action="http://databox.createsend.com/t/d/s/itkkyu/" method="post" class="subscribe-form" accept-charset="utf-8">
 <input id="fieldEmail" name="cm-itkkyu-itkkyu" class="input" type="email" placeholder="Your company email">
 <button class="get-notified" type="submit">Get notified</button>
</form>
```

js:

```
(function () {
    var count = 0;

    $('.subscribe-form button').click(function () {
        $('.subscribe-form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            count += 1;
        });

    if (count == 1) {
            console.log('oj');
            $('.subscribe-form').submit(function() {

            });

    }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Can you link to a fiddle or an example some where?  Not exactly sure what you want to do.  Is the user clicking the button once to slide it over, and then again after they type in their email?

Comment: Uhm, wouldn't you just do `if ( count === 0) e.preventDefault();` and just let the form submit when the count is more than zero ?

Comment: Yes, when button slide over it, the form must submit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery.one()` to add a one time event handler which cancels the submit, then use `jQuery.submit()` to trigger the submit event after whatever it is that you're doing is finished.

```
$('.subscribe-form').one('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do something
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Comment: This works, but what if the OP wanted to submit after three clicks? I posted a solution that can work for whatever threshold of the counter you'd like.

Comment: True, I'm just extrapolating from the fact that the OP had a counter... In your case, you're going to submit the form on the first click anyway, I'm not sure what the point of calling `e.preventDefault()` is since you're calling submit. I guess you could do something asychronously. From what the OP posted, it sounded like they wanted to submit the second time it was clicked? It's kind of hard to tell the real intention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this construction. Submit method will run only on second click.

```
(function () {
    var submit = false;
    $('.subscribe-form button').click(function (e) {
        if (!submit) {
            e.preventDefault();
            submit = true;
            return;
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to handle the click of the button, just the submit event. All you have to do is not call `e.preventDefault()` when you do want it submitted.

```
(function () {
  var count = 0;
    $('.subscribe-form').submit(function(e) {
        if (count < 1) {
          e.preventDefault();
          count += 1;
        }
    }
});
```